# UI5 composite control binding

Tags: sapui5

I have created a new control that is supposed to be an umbrella for a button and when you click on it, a MessagePopover is shown.

Hence my control has an aggregation called *items* which is forwarded using the *"forwarding:"* clause to the MessagePopover. My problem is, the button should show the *"getItems().length"* item count as text and I can't find a working solution for that.

```
text: "{= ${items}.length } ????"
```

See example here:

https://jsbin.com/joterew/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very close, you're just missing the slash

```
text: "{= ${/items}.length } ????"
```

here's an update: https://jsbin.com/kanuyolura/edit?html,output